# Windows Files-OnDemand Context status column

Tags: .net, windows-shell, shell-extensions

## Files On-Demand

We must prepare the application similar to OneDrive on Windows - synchronization list of files stored in cloud and synchronization of selected files.

During the investigation we found a very nice library to manage On-Demand Files in Windows from C# - [ShellBoost](https://www.shellboost.com/Doc/Introduction/Overview).

### List files from the cloud as local files

Show list of on-demand files in a local folder
[image: file-list]

Show folder with files as Namespace extension
[image: file-list-ext]

With [ShellBoost](https://www.shellboost.com/Doc/Introduction/Overview) we can synchronize files in a very cool way. We can show sync status, we can do all operations like on regular files, additionally, we can synchronize items or remove them from synchronization.

Unfortunately, we met some restrictions

### File Status column problem

Problem is that with [ShellBoost](https://www.shellboost.com/Doc/Introduction/Overview) and Files On-Demand we can't set additional icons in the status column like OneDrive does it

[image: onedrive-status]

#### Example

Here is a repo with the example
https://github.com/m4tchl0ck/ShellBoost-My-Samples

Comment: Are you using a ShellBoost Shell Namepace Extension or the ShellBoost's Files on-demand feature? Or Both?

Comment: Files on-demand feature, with Shell Namepace Extension files are not available from hard drive directory

Comment: Your sample seems to mix both features which are technically unrelated, so it's not very clear what you're trying to do. The files-on-demand feature enables the NTFS Cloud Folder API and handles synchronization. In this case the Shell UI is not handled by ShellBoost, so you must do it yourself using a WinRT state provider (demonstrated in CloudMirror sample https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/main/Samples/CloudMirror/CloudMirror/CustomStateProvider.cpp).

Comment: In this example, I tried many ways :).
Thanks for the sample we will check it and will back